# Is it possible to scrape data excluding child class within html node using Rvest?

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a URL `(https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8829402-Atlas-V6-Oil-Change-Routine)` to scrape the posts from. Some of these posts are replies which has initial text as "Originally Posted by ...". I want to scrape all the data within the posts excluding the initial Originally posted by text. For example,

```
User  df_text
 A    Hi, how are you ?
 B    This is beautiful!
 C    Heuwi
 D    Originally posted by C Heuwi 
      Hellou
 E    Hello guys
 F    Originally posted by A Hi, how are you ?
      I am doing good
 G    Whats going on ?
```

For user D, "Originally Posted by.." is under div.quote_container class (child class) and "I am doing good" is under blockquote.postcontent.restore, which is parent class.

Expected results:

```
User  df_text
 A    Hi, how are you ?
 B    This is beautiful!
 C    Heuwi
 D    Hellou
 E    Hello guys
 F    I am doing good
 G    Whats going on ?
```

I tried the following code:

```
url<-"https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8829402-Atlas-V6-Oil-Change-Routine"
review <- read_html(url)
threads<- cbind(review %>% html_nodes("blockquote.postcontent.restore:not(.quote_container)") %>% html_text())
```

Tried few other ones too:

```
threads <- cbind(review %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="blockquote.postcontent.restore"]/node()[not(self::div)]') %>% html_text())
```

or

```
threads <- review %>% html_nodes(".content")
close_nodes <- threads %>% html_nodes(".quote_container")
chk <- xml_remove(close_nodes)
```

None of these worked. Please help me to find a way to scrape all the posts data excluding child class. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out to be a relevantly easy solution by using the `xml_remove` function which is a part of the xml2 library (loaded automatically with rvest)

```
library(rvest)
#read page
url<-"https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?8829402-Atlas-V6-Oil-Change-Routine"
review <- read_html(url)

#find parent nodes
threads<- review %>% html_nodes("blockquote.postcontent.restore:not(.quote_container)")
#find children nodes to exclude
toremove<-threads %>% html_node("div.bbcode_container")
#remove nodes
xml_remove(toremove)

#convert the parent nodes to text
threads %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)
```

From the documentation for `xml_remove`: "*Care needs to be taken when using xml_remove()*". Please review, use caution and save frequently.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. Can this be used within a loop as well ?

Comment: @gamyanaidu, yes this method should be able to extend to a loop.

Comment: is it possible to exclude multiple nodes here? 
I tried the code it does not work 
`url <- "https://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?3087297-How-to-solve-(or-prevent)-Eos-Roof-leaks"
review <- read_html(url)
threads<- review %>% html_nodes("blockquote.postcontent.restore:not(.quote_container):not(.cms_table)")
#find children nodes to exclude
toremove<-threads %>% html_node("div.bbcode_container")
tormove2<-threads %>% html_node("tbody")
#remove nodes
xml_remove(toremove)
xml_remove(tormove2)
#convert the parent nodes to text
thread <-threads %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)`

Comment: @gamyanaidu, I am not sure, you have to be careful since one is changing the structure of the xml page.  Thus you may experience some unexpected behavior.

Comment: By changing the "tbody" with immediate child node, it works.