# rvest object cloned with rlang::duplicate is not properly cloned

Tags: r, rvest, rlang

`rvest` doesn't seem to offer any way to extract text from parent object only (ignoring children).  One [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54789039/1156245) uses `xml_remove()`, which mutates the original object - all the way up the memory chain given R's default lazy evaluation.

I look to `rlang::duplicate()`, which is supposed for *"modifying the copy leaves the original object intact"*, but the clone does not appear to be truly independent.  For example:

```
require(rvest)

h = '<ul>
<li id="target">
text to extract
<ul><li>text to ignore</li><li>this too</li></ul>
</li>
</ul>'

doc = xml2::read_html(h)
x = html_node(doc, '#target')

html_text(x)
#> [1] "\ntext to extract\ntext to ignorethis too"
```

Now clone x, remove its children, and extract the text:

```
x2 = rlang::duplicate(x, shallow = FALSE)
children = html_children(x2)
xml2::xml_remove(children)
html_text(x2)
#> [1] "\ntext to extract\n"
```

That works as intended, however x has also been mutated:

```
html_text(x)
#> [1] "\ntext to extract\n"
```

Any suggestions why and how to workaround this?  I do not want to start re-attaching children..

Comment: `data.table::copy()` delivers the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all let me say that I think yoo can solve the issue without copying the data. I'm not an expert in xpath, but I think you can use it to just select only direct text descendents, ignoring text nested in other xml nodes. I.e. the following seems to do the trick without any copy (`x` defined as in your question):

```
html_text(html_elements(x, xpath = "text()"))
# [1] "\ntext to extract\n"
```

That being said, I also have an answer to the question on how to make a deep copy:

The problem is that `rlang::duplicate()` can only copy R data structures. However, `rvest` builds on `xml2`, and `xml2` builds on the C library `libxml2`.

When you create the `xml_node` object in R, the corresponding data structure is created in `libxml2`. On the R side, there is basically just a pointer to the `libxml2` object. So `rlang::duplicate()` will only create a copy of that pointer, but not of the underlying data. It cannot do so, because it has no access to it as it is in a different library (that `rlang` doesn't know of).

The easiest way to create a copy of the underlying data seems to be to serialize and deserialze the xml. I suspect this is not very efficent though.

Example:

Read in the original data:

```
require(rvest)

h <- '<ul>
<li id="target">
text to extract
<ul><li>text to ignore</li><li>this too</li></ul>
</li>
</ul>'


doc <- xml2::read_html(h)
x <- html_node(doc, '#target')
```

Create two copies - one with `rlang:duplicate()` and one with `xml2::xml_unserialize()`:

```
x1 <- rlang::duplicate(x, shallow = FALSE)
x2 <- xml2::xml_unserialize(xml2::xml_serialize(x, NULL))
```

Check that `x` and `x1` are in fact identical, while `x2` is a true copy (the memory locations you get will be of course be different to the ones shown here):

```
x$doc
# <pointer: 0x0000023911334ea0>
x1$doc
# <pointer: 0x0000023911334ea0>  
# --> same as x
x2$doc
# <pointer: 0x00000239113377d0>
# --> different to x
```

Test that everything works as intented:

```
children <- html_children(x2)
xml2::xml_remove(children)

html_text(x2)
# [1] "\n    text to extract\n    "
html_text(x)
# [1] "\n    text to extract\n    text to ignorethis too"
```

Comment: This looks very promising let me test tomorrow :)

Comment: You've nailed it! Thanks very much AEF, I'll award the bounty as soon as page lets me.

Comment: The reason the xpath solution won't work is that my parent text contains <a> tags that I do want to preserve, so I need controi over which children to remove, ajd the unserialize approach solves that.

Comment: Glad I could help :) I'm quite certain that there would be a fitting xpath-expression for your use case anyway (e.g. you could try `html_text(html_elements(x, xpath = "text()|a"))`), but depending on how complex your documents are, it may be cumbersome to create/find it. So maybe the duplication is really the easiest option.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential solution (maybe a more general approach) is to use the `html_children()` function to obtain the text of all the child nodes and then remove that from the full text.

```
require(rvest)

h = '<ul>
<li id="target">
text to extract
<ul><li>text to ignore</li><li>this too</li></ul>
</li>
</ul>'

doc = xml2::read_html(h)
x = html_node(doc, '#target')

fulltext <- html_text(x)
# [1] "\ntext to extract\ntext to ignorethis too"

#find the text in the children nodes
childtext <- html_children(x) %>% html_text()
# "text to ignorethis too"

#replace the child node text with a numm
gsub(childtext, "", fulltext) %>% trimws() 
#"text to extract"


    #alternative using the text from the first child node
    firstchild <- xml_child(x, search=1) %>% xml_text()
    gsub(paste0(firstchild, ".*"), "", fulltext)
```

Of course, if there are additional newline "\n" or formatting character, the `gsub()` may break.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this might be possible but does feel hacky and unnecessary computational burden. Still appreciated :)