# R, rvest, text scraping - drop specific elements from a HTML node, based on their tags

Tags: r, xpath, rvest

Here is a quick mock-code

```
<div class = "speech">

<p>
<a id = "xxxx"> </a>
<b> <a href = "xxxx"> xxxx </a> </b>
Text text text <i> text </i> text
<br>
text text <sup> text </sup> text
</p>

<p>
<a id = "xxxx"> </a>
<b> <a href = "xxxx"> xxxx </a> </b>
Text text text <i> text </i> text
<br>
text text <sup> text </sup> text
</p>

</div>
```

I want to get a list or data frame with the text content of each "p" node concatenated as an unique entry of this list/data frame.
So, basically, I want to drop the "a" and "b" sub-node from the result and at the same it the text content of each "p" tag make for one string entry in a list/dataframe, without the "i", "br" and "sup" tags (but still the text that is inside these tags.

Many thanks in advance !

Here is my code:

```
GET(url = "https://xxx") %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@class = 'speech']//text()") %>%
  as.character()
```

I am stuck here. What is get is a list, with text elements, but:

- The "i", "sup" and "br" tags make a separation in this list, whereas I want the whole text content of each "p" node to be in one entry in this list

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Can you share your code and explain?

Comment: @QHarr Done, I have added my code as well as clarification bits, thank you in advance

Comment: So, you would expect a single string (made up of the content of the `p` tags) inside a column of one row of a dataframe?

Comment: That's it, exactly.

Comment: This is closer to what you want: `page%>%html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@class = 'speech']//p") %>% html_text()` then maybe some string editing. This also may help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54787882/is-it-possible-to-scrape-data-excluding-child-class-within-html-node-using-rvest/54789039#54789039

Comment: @Dave2e This is great help, thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `foo.html` be the file containing your example html:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

doc <-
  read_html("foo.html") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//p") %>%
  as_xml_document(root = ".")

xml_remove(
  doc %>% xml_find_all(xpath = "//a|b")
)

doc %>%
  as_list() %>%
  pluck(".") %>%
  map(~ .x %>% purrr::simplify() %>% paste0(collapse = " "))
```

Output:

```
$p
[1] "\n \n list(\" \", \" \") \nText text text  list(\" text \")  text\n list() \ntext text  list(\" text \")  text\n"

$p
[1] "\n \n list(\" \", \" \") \nText text text  list(\" text \")  text\n list() \ntext text  list(\" text \")  text\n"
```

Comment: That's a great solution, thank you very much for your help and time.